# LibVLCSharp: Why does RTSP stream's aspect ratio not change when setting AspectRatio and Scale?

Tags: c#, winforms, vlc, aspect-ratio, libvlcsharp

I'm using `LibVLCSharp` and the `VideoView` control from `LibVLCSharp.WinForms` to display RTSP streams using Windows Forms. I'm having trouble setting the `AspectRatio`. I implemented a method to set the `AspectRatio` based on my configuration given in `aspectRatio`:

```
public void SetAspectRatio(eAspectRatio aspectRatio)
{            
    if (_mediaPlayer != null)
    {
        switch (aspectRatio)
        {
            case eAspectRatio.Original:
                _mediaPlayer.AspectRatio = null;
                _mediaPlayer.Scale = 1;
                break;

            case eAspectRatio._4_3:
                _mediaPlayer.AspectRatio = "4:3";
                _mediaPlayer.Scale = 0;
                break;

            case eAspectRatio._16_9:
                _mediaPlayer.AspectRatio = "16:9";
                _mediaPlayer.Scale = 0;
                break;

            case eAspectRatio.Fill:
                _mediaPlayer.Scale = 0;
                _mediaPlayer.AspectRatio = $"{videoView.Size.Width}:{videoView.Size.Height}";
                break;

            case eAspectRatio.BestFit:
                _mediaPlayer.AspectRatio = null;
                _mediaPlayer.Scale = 0;
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

I took the code from [this](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/master/src/LibVLCSharp/MediaPlayerElement/AspectRatioManager.cs) example. I'm using this method at several places in my code, mostly when an update of the aspect ratio is necessary, e.g. right before and after the stream was started or when the window is resized. Unfortunately this method does not work, the output video aspect ratio does not change in any way. Is it possible that the displayed stream does not support changing the `AspectRatio`? Or are there any other things I need to consider when changing/updating the `AspectRatio`?

I'm using pre-release versions of all LibVLCSharp components:

- LibVLCSharp: 4.0.0-alpha-20240110-7429
- LibVLCSharp.WinForms: 4.0.0-alpha-20240110-7429
- VideoLan.LibVLC.Windows: 4.0.0-alpha-20240116

Any help concerning this issue would be much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't find any issues reagrding this topic in the [official LibVLCSharp repository](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/tree/master?ref_type=heads) as well.